# why servlet hangs on auto refresh?

Tags: servlets

I use

```
response.setheader("refresh",10);
```

...to auto refresh servlet, but after performing 9-8 refreshing next time page loading goes to infinite stage i.e. It loads continuously and nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem your are seeing after refreshing 8-9 times has nothing to do with the Refresh header.

Do you get the same problem if you manually refresh your page 8-9 times using the F5 key in your browser? What is your servlet code doing?